# AngularJS apply class to parent element on event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ng-class

I have a form field:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="abc.user.name" ng-focus="abc.setFocus('name')" required>
</div>
```

What I need to do is set add a class to the parent element, here `<div class="form-group">`, when the input has focus and remove it when the field loses focus.

I know how to do this in jQuery, but not in an Angular way.  I have many form fields that need to behave like this, so I'm trying to avoid setting a variable and looking for that with an `ng-class`.  I'd rather have some way for the field to simple act on its parent, which I can use the same method in every form field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directive is possibly the simplest generic approach if all you need to do is manipulate the dom.

```
<div class="form-group" focus-class="focused">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="abc.user.name" required>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('focusClass', function(){
    return {
      link:function(scope, elem, attrs){
         elem.find('input').on('focus', function(){
            elem.toggleClass(attrs.focusClass);
         }).on('blur', function(){
            elem.toggleClass(attrs.focusClass);
         });
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  There was a tiny error in your code: it should be `elem.toggleClass(attrs.focusClass);` And you're right, I did need two listeners.  But a simple elegant solution.

Comment: Great.  I used `addClass` and `removeClass` instead of `toggleClass`, but I guess either way works.  This was a great solution, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this

```
    <div class="form-group {{focusIsSet ? 'is-focused': ''}}">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="abc.user.name" ng-focus="focusIsSet = true" ng-blur="focusIsSet = false" required>
    </div>
```

Where `$scope.focusIsSet` a boolean property. So depends of its state you can manage classes in `<div class="form-group">` with that expression `{{focusIsSet ? 'is-focused': ''}}`

You change it with `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` directives

**UPDATE**

I think you can hold states for each input with that way

```
<div class="form-group {{checkFocusState('abc.user.name') ? 'is-focused': ''}}">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="abc.user.name" ng-focus="setFocus('abc.user.name')" ng-blur="setBlur('abc.user.name')" required>
</div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
  var inputsFocusState = {};


  $scope.checkFocusState = function(propertyPathName) {

      if(inputsFocusState[propertyPathName] == true) {
         return true;
      }

      return false

  }

  $scope.setBlur = function(propertyPathName) {
         inputsFocusState[propertyPathName] = false;
  }

  $scope.setFocus = function(propertyPathName) {
         inputsFocusState[propertyPathName] = true;
  }
```

Otherwise, you can create each focus property for each input in html template

P.S. `ng-class` is good option too

P.S.S I had similar case, but forms were completely dynamic.

So I split each property in object like `user.name = {value: 'john', buttons: [...], label: 'Name', //and much more}`.

Also better to change `'user.name.path'` to something like `'user-name-path'`.

Comment: cleaner using `ng-class`

Comment: Agree with @charlietfl.  `ng-class="{ focused: focusIsSet }"`  Of course, this doesn't work since EVERY form field will be toggled.  I'm trying to avoid have to set a different variable for each field.